# Any way to make a page template inherit from another page template without the parent existing as a page in Kentico?

Tags: kentico

I have a generic page template that I wish to reuse for lots of pages, but each page also needs to have its own template within that. The generic page template might include a page banner and breadcrumbs for example.

The way I'm currently doing this is having every page be an ad-hoc clone of the generic template, however, this isn't easily managed when changes need to be made to the generic template itself as I then need to make that change on all ad-hoc templates too.

I could get around this by creating a new page that uses the generic template at the parent level and then nest all my pages under it, acting as a master page, but I feel like that's polluting the content tree unnecessarily as I already have a master template at the very root.

Is there a way to make page templates inherit from other templates without actually creating a physical master page in the content tree?

If it were possible to make specific webpart containers not shared to all pages that use the same template that would work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ad-hoc  are not good as you understand.

You can have 2 master templates: 1 will be your root, 2nd one down in the tree. All page under second master can inherit both templates at same time:
For example you have:

- the root master for the whole site that contains site menu and footer and placeholder
- your store master template for you store which has store menu and banner and placeholder.

All your products under the store master will inherit both store master and root master. For that you have to go 
template >specific ancestor pages > and check both masters : root and store

Another option to share content is add placeholder web part to your pages and point it to the shared page (you have to set "Page to display" property). I have a couple masters that are completely different but they share the same footer. So I have place holder on both of them  that point to this shared footer page.

Comment: Accepted this answer because of the inheritance detail. Checking both master pages fixed some stuff for me.

Answer (score 1):

Having a page template inherit from another template will work, the problem is if you don't use that page template on a page, there will be no content for the child page template to inherit from so defeats the purpose of inheritance.  Best bet would be to add those items to a parent page template.  Assuming a content tree like so:

- Page
  -- Page 1
  -- Page 2

On "Page" add your items in that template and hide or show them based on page type and or level.  Then for the "Page 1" and "Page 2" pages, set a default page template for those page types.  Then the user will not have to add or select a template, it will auto select for them.  Then all they ahve to do is add content for the banner under that "Page 1" or "Page 2" page.  The breadcrumbs should then auto show based on the child page showing or setting the node level.

Comment: Alright, I've gone this route because it doesn't look like there's any other way around it. Thanks anyway! My content tree is now like `WebsiteName -> Generic Template -> Content Page`, and I guess my next question would be how to make components like Breadcrumbs ignore that middle layer.